# Disable Apache Virtual Hosts for the IP, but not for the (sub)domains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I configured one domain and two subdomains, with a redirect to the corresponding https version:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName a.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://a.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName b.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://b.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I do some testing:

```
curl http://domain.com/ gives me the redirect to https://domain.com/
curl http://a.domain.com/ gives me the redirect to https://a.domain.com/
curl http://b.domain.com/ gives me the redirect to https://b.domain.com/
```

Great. A last test, just using the IP (a.b.c.d):

```
curl http://a.b.c.d/ gives me the redirect to https://a.domain.com/
```

It takes the redirect from the domain `a.domain.com`.

Is there any change to disbale HTTP/HTTPS, if the user requests `http://a.b.c.d/`? At the moment I added a redirect to the main domain, where the HTTPS-version has a self signed certificate (because it is just the IP):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect permanent / https://domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine ON
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key

  Redirect permanent / https://domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a default virtualhost without `ServerName` and without redirecting to any specific vhost. As I understand this is what you want. Apache uses as default the very first `VirtualHost` directive if finds in it's configuration files, so it would be enough to put a `ServerName`-less vhost into `httpd.conf` (or whatever it's called on your system) directly.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: I added ```<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect permanent / https://domain.com
</VirtualHost>``` as the very first `VirtualHost`. Thus, `curl http://a.b.c.d/ gives me the redirect to https://domain.com/` now.

Answer (score 0):

In a named VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine On
    ###other directives below
</VirtualHost>
```

This will always/force redirect users from http://example.com to https://example.com.

If you want users to have an option to use HTTP or HTTPS, have both configurations available. Do not redirect.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ###other directives below
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine On
    ###other directives below
</VirtualHost>
```

For an IP based configuration,the above setup would still work if you are just running one site in port 80 and one in 443.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80>
  ###other directives below
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:443>
    SSLEngine On
    ###other directives below
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is not answering my question at all.